# Fire jquery event on the invoke of certain jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using query scrolltoview plugin. Now my question is how i can bind certain jquery function or event when the plugin function starts executing 
Here is the jquery plugin function initializes

```
 $("#preff-supp").scrollintoview({duration: "slow"});
```

Any Hint ?

Comment: What does the scrollintoview documentation tell you? If you're using a plugin, they usually have events and callbacks you can hook into.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView) only shows a callback handler when the scroll events stops. This implies the plugin is incapable of doing what you need. You would have to amend the source, or find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#preff-supp").scrollintoview(onScroll());

function onScroll(){
    //Whatever code you want to do here
    alert("Scroll into view fired!");
    return {duration: "slow"};
}
```

It's a bit of a hack but it should work!

Comment: This will execute when the plugin is instantiated on the element, not when the scroll event fires.

Comment: I haven't been able to test it so you may well be right!